# Join two dataframes in pandas in a range

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrames
data1 = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         'Value1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}
data2 = {'Lower': [0, 20, 40],
         'Upper': [15, 35, 55],
         'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I want to join the dataframes where data1['Value1'] is between data2['Lower'] and data2['Upper']. In SQL it will be like

```
select * from 
data1 join data2
on
data1.Value1 >= data2['Lower']
and 
data1.Value1 <= data2['Upper']
```